# Xamarin Forms - Binding a function to StackLayout TapGesture

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my view I have:

```
<ContentView.BindingContext>
    <vm:HomeViewModel />
</ContentView.BindingContext>
```

In that viewmodel I have:

```
    public void test(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var x = 0;
    }
```

That's just for testing so I can hit a breakpoint, but I can't seem to Bind the function to the View:

```
                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White">
                    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding test }" />
                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
```

I've tried to hook it up with Tapped property as well, adding parentheses, I keep getting:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Position 57:51. No method OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped with correct signature found on type

I know I'm missing something here, can anyone shed some light on my problem?

Comment: as the name implies, you bind a **Command** to the `Command` property, not a **function**.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/commanding

Comment: That makes sense. I've tried using the Tapped property as well, but it wouldn't even let me compile. But I can assign a function to Tapped if I put in on the View itself. It doesn't seem to want to pull it from the BindingContext. Do I have to use a command to reach my ViewModel function? Or is there a way to feed the function directly? Is that poor practice? Just trying to keep my code behind clean.

Comment: it supports both a Tapped event and a Command.  You can use either depending on your needs.  If you use the event the handler needs to be defined in the code behind, where the Command can be bound to a property on your VM.

Comment: Ahh, I was afraid of that. No worries, I've hooked it up on the VM with a command execute and its working. Thank you for the quick replies and insight!

Comment: One more quick follow up, how do I access the sender from the command? it doesn't send one like onclick does, it seems. I want my stacklayouts background to alter when I tap it.

Comment: if that's what you want then just use an event handler in the code behind, since you're just modifying the View.  Otherwise you can bind the BackgroundColor to a VM property and use the Command to modify the bound property

Answer (score 0):

You need a command in your viewmodel binding to:

```
public ICommand cmdTest { get { return new Command(() => test())
```

Now in your view you are able to bind to cmdTest:

```
<TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding cmdTest}" />
```